# Read/Write pdf file in Scala

Tags: scala, pdf

I am new to Scala, and I was wondering weather there is a native way to read/write a PDF file?

I saw there is a java library called [pdfbox](https://pdfbox.apache.org/), but I'd rather use some other way which doesn't involve installing additional libraries, as my main goal for this project is to get into Scala programming.

Also - in case I do need to install a third party library, is SBT a good approach?

Comment: I doubt any language would have something as complex as reading a PDF on a _native way_. Yes PDF box is probably the best idea and yes sbt is the way to _"install"_ libraries. - Anyways, if your end goal is learn Scala and not read the PDF why did you choose this strange requisite?

Comment: PDFBox exists since 2002. And we still haven't implemented all the features. No, there is no easy way to read/write PDF (like html).

Comment: @LuisMiguelMejíaSuárez Thank you for clarifying. I didn't realize PDF was such a complex format to implement (I will look into that too). I've had this project in my had for some time, but never got around to realize it. I figured it could be an interesting way to learn more about Scala with it, that's all.

Comment: @Walrus if you want to focus on Scala, you may want to start with simpler projects. But, you can just continue with this idea of yours, you can easily use any java library from Scala.

Comment: https://www.adobe.com/content/dam/acom/en/devnet/pdf/pdfs/PDF32000_2008.pdf and that's just PDF. There are a few thousand more pages about font formats.